# Containerizing my app developed w/ Anaconda, using Docker

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, geospatial, container-image

My first question here, so I am sorry if I did not follow a community guideline or if this is the wrong place to post. I am a rookie developer (still a student), and I created some geospatial analytics applications using the Anaconda distribution of Python, and they are pretty heavy on certain dependencies, many of which are a total pain to install and configure correctly.  I was hoping to containerize the application so that further development and deployment can be more seamless (my time in this research group is coming to an end, and I want future developers to not have to go through the same pains).  I am trying to use Docker to do this, but am having trouble finding documentation for something similar (I want to use my specific environment or environment settings as the environment for the container, not someone else's Anaconda environment configuration).  Does anyone know how I could go about this or have a link to helpful documentation?

For context, this is my first time using Docker - and I am pretty new to Anaconda as well.

I was following this tutorial, but it seems to instead use a ready-made environment from an online repo (I tried modifying with my own local custom environment, but was not successful).

http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Tutorial:_Docker_Anaconda_Python_--_4

One of my applications' main file is a normal python file, the other uses a Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Figured it out!  Was a bit tricky with a lot of pitfalls along the way.  Helpful sources: http://www.easy-analysis.com/dockerizing-python-flask-app-and-conda-environment/   and https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9480